# Directly Rendering raster to Google Map API from Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am using Google Earth Engine Python API for calculating NDVI and then sending the NDVI result to Google cloud storage. After that I am displaying the result (NDVI tiles stored in Google bucket/cloud storage) at front end using Google Map API. But exporting the result from Earth Engine to bucket takes average 5 to 10 minuets depending on my ROI. Now Earth Engine API itself can render the output within few seconds.

My question, is it possible to directly render the raster output on Google Map API from Google Earth Engine (without storing the result to bucket.. as storing result in Google bucket takes much more time)?

Answer (score 1):

You can get map tiles directly using getMapId and getTileUrl.  There are examples of doing this in the demos section of the earth engine api github repo:
https://github.com/google/earthengine-api/tree/master/demos